# Is the jQuery fadeIn() the correct method to use here?

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have a red line rotating in a circular motion (left to right, clockwise but starts bottom left). As is, it works fine, **but there should be a nice fade effect when the red goes to white.** Currently that is not the case.

See the attached image: below is what I'm trying to achieve. [image]

The current code for the rotation in place is:

```
function drawcmitimer(percent){
    $('div.cmitimer').html('<div class="percent"></div><div id="slice"'+(percent > 50?' class="gt50"':'')+'><div class="pie"></div>'+(percent > 50?'<div class="pie fill"></div>':'')+'</div>');
    var deg = 360/100*percent;
    $('#slice .pie').css({
        '-moz-transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)',
        '-o-transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)',
        'transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)'
    });
}
```

If I add a `display: none` to the `.css` above and then a `.fadeIn(1000, 1)` at the end, nothing breaks and the same behavior continues (ie no fade).

To do a test, I just tried a 'simpler' `fadeOut` like so:

```
$('#slice .pie').css({
    '-moz-transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)',
    '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)',
    '-o-transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)',
    'transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)'
}).fadeOut("fast");
```

What I noticed was that the red line would all the way around, and after about ten seconds the whole red circle would fade out.

This codeshare shows the whole JS file to give you an idea, just didn't want to paste the whole thing here: http://codeshare.io/b1lPX

Any input on how to get the fadeIn effect on the red line is appreciated.

Comment: `fadeIn` changes the color over time. If you want the change over a range of space, that's a _gradient_.

Comment: I see your point. For now the timer is hardcoded (see the codeshare) but this will be updated based on how long the flight is. So technically it's over a space (a measured div) AND over a timeframe. So couldn't `fadeIn` work?

Comment: I think @Barmar has it right that you need to look into the gradient aspect.  What you're doing with `.fadeOut()` is fading out the entire circle, not just the end of it.  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding

Comment: No not misunderstanding :) I just feel like with the other two JS functions in place (see Codeshare) there should be a way to implement a fade on the end. Anyways, will look into the gradient effect for now.